Movie about a female thief or assassin who has a doppelganger falls asleep in bathtub with water running, she sees her future
Looking for a movie that involves a female thief or assassin who has a doppelganger falls asleep in the bathtub with water running and basically sees her future involving a chain of events, sun comes out from clouds and reflects of photographer camera setting up a wedding shot, the reflection blinds a truck driver, who crashes, the commotion distracts the thief and doesnt see a gun as she gets shot.
The movie takes place in France i believe, theres also another photographer who has been taking pictures different times of the day of the same building from the same spot.
When i first researched the movie it was said to be a film noir(dreams, water and mirrors, crime etc...) also thought daryl hannah was the female 

its Femme Fatale from 2002 
Strangely I searched for it, but the cover and the opening lines I saw in the search didn't seem like it.

A woman tries to straighten out her life, even as her past as a
  con-woman comes back to haunt her.





You might want to elaborate in which way this fits the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
